# Unable to send email by smtplib in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, eclipse, email, smtplib

I am trying to send email using smtplib in my Django 1.11 project but getting

```
"Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow."
```

error and compiler terminates without to exception.

This same code was working fine before. I have not updated anything, Python version or Django version but this same code stopped working now.

I am using Python version 3.6.8, Django version 1.11 and my IDE is Eclipse.

here is my function:

```
def emailSendingFunctionTest(Subject, Message, EmailAddress, leadCaptureEmailStatusId, assignedToId):
    sender = Constants.EmailConfig_Email() 
    MESSAGE = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    MESSAGE['SUBJECT'] = Subject        
    receivers = EmailAddress
    HTML_BODY = MIMEText(Message, 'html')
    MESSAGE.attach(HTML_BODY)

    try:

        server = smtplib.SMTP(Constants.EmailConfig_SMTP())
        server.starttls()
        server.verify(EmailAddress)
        server.login(Constants.EmailConfig_Email(), Constants.EmailConfig_Password())
        server.sendmail(sender, receivers, MESSAGE.as_string())
        server.quit()
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

    except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
        print(str(e))

    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
```

I am calling this function from an other function like this:

```
emailSendingFunctionTest(subject, message, emailAddressAssignedTo, leadCaptureEmailStatusId, newLead["assignedToId"])
```

I have attached the screenshot  of errors i am facing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Django has nice wrappers for [sending email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#module-django.core.mail). I think you're making your code more complicated than it needs to be by using smtplib directly.

Comment: @NullPointer: thank you for wanting to edit questions here. Some editing tips: (1) please don't add homemade tags to questions - that is what the tag system is for. Questions should be ordinary English sentences, either a statement or a question. (2) Please don't add `code formatting` to frameworks or programming languages - they are not themselves code. I have removed that formatting. These are called "proper nouns" and just benefit from observing the correct case (usually an initial capital letter).

Comment: Haroon, please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.